# WebDAV support in Microsoft Edge browser?

Tags: internet-explorer, webdav, windows-10, microsoft-edge

Having a productive WebApplication for 10 years supporting

- starting a WebDAV Session from the WebApplication using     `url(#default#httpFolder)`
- starting Editing Office-Documents using                                   `Active-X SharePoint.OpenDocuments()` call

in all Versions of Internet Explorer,
we now wonder how to achieve this functionality in the upcoming Edge Browser.

Are there any replacement calls to again support this 2 scenarios?